# Testing Expression over region of values

Tags: evaluation, symbols

I'd like to test whether this expression is negative when a and b are constrained to lie within (0,1) interval. Any ideas how?

```
D[Integrate[((1 - (a*x))^12)*((1 + (a/b))/((1 + (a*x/b))^2)), {x, 0, 1}], a]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr1 = ((1 - (a*x))^12)*((1 + (a/b))/((1 + (a*x/b))^2)) // Simplify;
```

Evaluating the integral

```
int = Assuming[0 < a <= 1 && 0 < b <= 1,
   Integrate[expr1, {x, 0, 1}] // Simplify];
```

Taking the derivative

```
expr2 = D[int, a] // Simplify[#, 0 < a <= 1 && 0 < b <= 1] &;
```

Numerically finding the minimum

```
NMinimize[{expr2, 0 < a <= 1, 0 < b <= 1}, {a, b},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

{-6., {a -> 8.10042*10^-9, b -> 0.91264}}

Limit[expr2, a -> 0]

(* -6 *)
```

The minimum occurs when `a` is near `0`

```
Limit[expr2, a -> 0]

(* -6 *)
```

**EDIT:** numerically finding the maximum

```
NMaximize[{expr2, 0 < a <= 1, 0 < b <= 1}, {a, b},
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {-1.00973*10^-12, {a -> 0.981099, b -> 9.7192*10^-13}} *)
```

The maximum occurs for `b` near `0`

```
Limit[expr2, b -> 0]

(* 0 *)
```

Consequently, `expr2` is nonpositive **everywhere** in the region. Graphically,

```
Plot3D[expr2, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 Exclusions -> True,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15,
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bob. Shouldn't the last step be a maximization as I want to verify if the expression is always less than 0 e.g. that it's max value < 0? Also do you know why it isn't possible to do analytically rather than numerically?

Comment: The expression is transcendental. Terms include product of high order polynomial times a log. Analytic solution is unlikely.